# Unity collider depreciated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
```

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public PlayerMovement movement;

void OnCollisionEnter(PlayerCollision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.GetComponent<Collider>("obstacle").
    {
        Debug.Log("we hit an obstacle!");
    }
}
```

}

using this code from a tutorial i have wrote this code in my given situation but every time i try to test the game i am making i get the error in unity 2017.4.0f1 of the following

Assets/PlayerCollision.cs(9,27): error CS0619: `UnityEngine.Component.collider' is obsolete:`Property collider has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'

i sort of understand this but don't at the same time so i was wondering how to apply this to my written code on the top of this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For your information C is not C# is not C

Comment: I fail to see where the depreciated `property` is and you're already calling `GetComponent`. You do however have an error in your code; `if (collisionInfo.GetComponent<Collider>("obstacle").` should probably be `if (collisionInfo.GetComponent<Collider>() != null)`

Comment: @Lece That's true. I suspect that OP posted the wrong code but the error shows that OP is trying to access `collider` directly without using `GetComponent`. Also, that should be `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)` not `void OnCollisionEnter(PlayerCollision collisionInfo)`. I wonder what else is wrong in that code.

Comment: @Programmer yes good point! `Collision` does contain a `Collider` property so I guess `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) { if(collision.collider.GetComponent<PlayerCollision>() != null) { // DoSomething } }` would make more sense.